# How to overlay one CGImage over another

Tags: cocoa, cgimage, cgimageref

I wish to overlay one CGImage over another.

As an example the first CGImage is 1024x768 and want to overlay a second 100x100 CGImage at a given location.

I have seen how to do this using NSImage but don't really want to convert my CGImages to NSImage's then do overlay then convert the result back to CGImage. I have also seen iOS versions of the code, but unsure how to go about it on Mac?

Comment: The iOS code should actually work on OS X, since the CoreGraphics APIs are identical on both platforms.

Comment: @KevinBallard Unfortunately the iOS example I found uses drawRect to render the overlaid image.. http://www.craftymind.com/2009/02/10/creating-the-loupe-or-magnifying-glass-effect-on-the-iphone/  not sure if I can get the context from first image and somehow do a CGContextDrawImage onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mostly used to iOS, so I might be out of my depth here, but assuming you have a graphics context (sized like the larger of the two images), can't you just draw the two CGImages on top of each other?

```
CGImageRef img1024x768;
CGImageRef img100x100;

CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(img1024x768), CGImageGetHeight(img1024x768));

CGRect largeBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(img1024x768), CGImageGetHeight(img1024x768));
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, largeBounds, img1024x768);

CGRect smallBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(img100x100), CGImageGetHeight(img100x100));
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, smallBounds, img100x100);
```

And then draw the result into a NSImage?

Comment: You are correct this is the way to go about this, however i had a problem getting a context in first place. In the end i refactored my code to use NSImage